# How to update relation field in override save

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-2.0

How to update relation `OneToOneField` field in override save

update working in `object.create()` but not working in `.save()`

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.wallet.wallet_inventory = 50
        self.wallet.save()
        super(MonthlyBuyerOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

models.py

```
class OrdersGift(models.Model):
    minPrice = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    giftPrice = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    gift_description = models.TextField(null=True, max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['minPrice']


class BuyerUserWallet(models.Model):
    buyer = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False)
    success_order = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    unSuccess_order = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    total_order = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    wallet_inventory = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    use_gift_order = models.ManyToManyField(BuyerOrders)


class MonthlyBuyerOrder(models.Model):
    wallet = models.ForeignKey(BuyerUserWallet, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False)
    monthly_order_total = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    success_orders = models.ManyToManyField(BuyerOrders)
    gift = models.ForeignKey(OrdersGift, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    giftPrice = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)

    def save(self, force_insert=False,
             force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        self.wallet.wallet_inventory = 120
        self.wallet.save()
        super(MonthlyBuyerOrder, self).save(force_insert=False,
                                            force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None)
```

custom save function also does not work

Answer (score 0):

It should work by both method save_base or save.
In the original question, you were defining save_base and overriding that from super().save(*args, **kwargs)

```
def save_base(self, raw=False, force_insert=False,
              force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    self.wallet.wallet_inventory = 50
    self.wallet.save()
    super(MonthlyBuyerOrder, self).save_base(raw=False, force_insert=False,
              force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None)
```

Comment: not working !```    def save(self, force_insert=False,
             force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        self.wallet.wallet_inventory = 120
        self.wallet.save()
        super(MonthlyBuyerOrder, self).save(force_insert=False,
                                            force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None)```

Comment: use this ```save(self, *args, **kwargs):
self.wallet.wallet_inventory = 120 
self.wallet.save() 
super(MonthlyBuyerOrder, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)```

Comment: Sorry my bad 
save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
self.wallet.wallet_inventory = 120 
 self.wallet.save()  
super(MonthlyBuyerOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)